# WAMP Проблемы с dll

Tags: php, dll, wamp

На Windows установлен сервер `WAMP`, все устанавливалось отдельно, все 64 битное, при выполнении скриптов в `cli` вылетают предупреждения:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library C:\Server\PHP\ext\php_interbase.dll (php_oci8_12.dll, php_pdo_firebird.dll, php_pdo_oci.dll, php_pspell.dll, php_sysbase_ct.dll) not be found. in Unknown on line 0

Предупреждения то ладно но  не могу установить composer

Comment: Попробуйте исключить расширение interbase c помощью соответствующего флажка в меню wamp. Есть альтернативный вариант замьютить startup errors вообще, но я бы его не рекомендовал.

Comment: @Etki  замьютить startup errors вообще, но я бы его не рекомендовал.          Почему?

Comment: Потому что в случае возникновения других ошибок их станет очень сложно отследить.

Answer (score 1):

Проверь в `php.ini` путь до дирректории с PHP расширениями. И попробуй изменить на полный путь как в Windows (вроде только слэши обратные), если это не так.

Comment: Пути правильные, где-то слышал что бывают проблемы с `PHP` на `Windows`, поэтому даже переустанавливал сервер, на 32 битную. А насчет `WAMP` у меня отдельно стоит `Apache 2.4, Mysql 5.6 и PHP 5.6.8`